# Section doesn't show up on mobile, but does in dev tools

Tags: css, wordpress

Having a really weird issue with this section on the contact and home page...

http://tecnoempaque.com.do/contacto/

Only on phones the phone number text doesn't show up. It does in dev tools when i select different devices. I have an iphone (safari)

I just asked my friend to go to the site on her phone that has chrome. Seems to work. Maybe it's CSS comparability with safari?  But the classes should be identical.. It's a popular theme so would've guessed this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Which phone number?? the header one?? please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Safari can be a little wonky if you add

```
.fusion-content-boxes .content-container{-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

It should resolve any issue with Safari i did notice you had some data-animation attributes in the parent tags. I've had issues with Animations loading correctly in Safari when its a pre-built theme.

Comment: Thanks. You happen to try this in Safari? Don't think its working but could be in a media query in the theme